# Git telling me to pull, then commit, then pull?

Tags: git, github

I am trying to push new changes, but I have a conflicted file. After trying to push, I get the following error:

```
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the
'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
```

Ok, so we need to use git pull.
I try to use `git pull` and then I get this error:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    db/profile_edit.php
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
```

But, when I try to commit, I go back to the first error. What should I do? The changes on the remote repo are newer than the ones on my local machine. So, how do I open it up with a diff tool and make the changes and then tell git that I have made changes so it will let me push changes?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try to do

```
$ git pull --rebase
```

To pull remote changes before yours, and then commit. And see if it works.

If this does not work, try this instead:

```
$ git stash
$ git pull --rebase
$ git stash pop
```

To save your changes on the `stash`, apply remote commits inside your work-repository, and then apply your changes (saved into `stash`) inside your work-repository again.

Answer (score 8):

First, I think if you were to `git add` then `git commit`, your local repo would be clean enough to do a `git pull`.

However, if there may be changes you don't want to commit until you see what happened on the upstream, you can use `git stash`. It will temporarily clean up your working directory and save your changes, so you can pull (I would recommend `git pull --rebase` to avoid merge points - but it is a personal taste issue). Once you have upstream changes pulled, you can get your local modifications back using `git stash pop`. After you clean up conflicts and get rid of unnecessary changes, you can add, commit, then finally push.

Answer (score 5):

You're getting yourself confused with the commands.

`git commit` saves changes into git's database
`git pull` brings remote commits into your repo

You're trying to **pull** with uncommitted changes, so git is asking you to **commit** those first (or `git stash` them away) so that it can merge your local changes with the remote ones.