# Git tells me my changes haven't been committed, even though they have been?

Tags: django, git, commit

I was trying to clean up my directory by deleting no longer relevant files. Since then,  whenever I try to push, I get the error "Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge: [list of some files I tried deleting]. Please commit or stash them before you can merge" which is odd because all my other file deletions were committed successfully.

EDIT: I renamed my local copy and cloned the repo again, and discovered that the changes I made /were/ going through, but for some reason the web app itself hasn't been reflecting those changes. I tried clearing my browser's cache and viewing the website on other browsers, but those changes just don't appear anywhere except in the files I cloned, which baffles me completely.

1. Is there any explanation for why the web app is not displaying the most recently updated files?
2. I still get this error, if it sheds any light:

   > > > "Your local changes to the following file would be overwritten by merge:
   > > >       static/css/newcss.css
   > > >       Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.

Despite the fact that I have not altered that file in any way since cloning it.

(Also note, I'm using Django for this web app)

EDIT EDIT: So I guess to close this question, the updating of the site was just taking a long time to process (like, two weeks long).

Comment: what does `git status` display now?

Comment: git status gives me "nothing to commit (working directory clean)"

Comment: Does the repository you are trying to push to have a working directory associated with it (i.e. it is not a bare repository)? Are there uncommitted changes in that working directory that the commits you are pushing would overwrite?

Comment: @twalberg I don't think I have any bare repositories. How would I find out about the status/existence of other working directories?

Answer (score 0):

When i use GIT, i usually get this kind of strange errors.

Have you try this: [Git telling me to pull, then commit, then pull?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6769644/git-telling-me-to-pull-then-commit-then-pull)

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain you committed your changes? Run this:

```
git diff
```

If something comes up, it means there are changes in your working directory that don't match your last commit, e.g., that is the change that needs to be committed.

Try committing the file that changed:

```
git add myfile.txt
git commit myfile.txt -m "Committing my file"
```

Comment: git diff didn't return anything, so I feel like git is worrying about files that no longer exist?